# Event to.owl.carousel and items > 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Why does event `to.owl.carousel` work incorrectly with `items` > 1? When I try to switch to slide 1, it scrolls through 2 slides in a row instead.

https://codepen.io/photosho/pen/abqKJbw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this issue, they address that the `to.owl.carousel` will take 3 params `[position, speed, offset]`.

https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/421

Please try the below code:

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$('input').val(), 100, 1]);
  });
```